# why is my first transition effect being canceled out by my second transition effect?

Tags: html, css

I created a transition effect in my `.speech-bubble`so that the "click to copy text" promt would fade in when the copy button was hovered on, and it was working and fading in until I added a second transition effect to my code in `.button:hover + .speech-bubble` and that code would create a transition effect when the copy button was pressed. But when I added that second prompt in the first fade in one stopped working. I would really appreciate help  on how to fix this, thank you for reading, my code is below.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
  var output= document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
}

function maFunction(el) { //update : el
  //el.classList.add('clicked');// update 
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'text copied!';
  document.getElementById("foo").classList.add("mystyle");
  var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

function right() {
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'click to copy text';
  document.getElementById("foo").classList.replace("mystyle","ok");
}

/*function ok() {
  document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
*/

/*function fadeOut(){
 location.href='index.html#open-modal';
 setTimeout(function () {
     location.href='index.html#modal-close';
     }, 1000);
}*/
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    
}

 .input {
    height: 700px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.otput {
    height: 695px;
    width: 620px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

 .output {
    height: 650px;
    width: 512px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    /*margin-left: 1134px;*/
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

.speech-bubble {
    height: 25px;
    width: 170px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 background: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    /*display: none;*/
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 630px;
    transform: translateY(-690px);
    opacity: 0;
    /*my first transition effect*/
    transition: opacity 200ms
}
.speech-bubble:after {
    content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 9px solid transparent;
 border-right-color: #4CAF50;
 border-left: 0;
 margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}


.button:hover + .speech-bubble {
    opacity: 1;
    /*my second transition effect*/
    transition: width 100ms;
}

.mystyle {
    width: 120px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.button:hover + .speech-bubble:after {
    display: block;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}


/*.modal-window {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal-window:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-window > div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    /*padding: 2rem;*/
    /*background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.modal-window .copy{
    font-size: 20px;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <textarea class="input"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>

    <form class="otput">

    <textarea class="output" id="output" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
    <input class="button" id="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction(),setTimeout(right, 1000)"><!-- update on onclick -->
    
    <p class="speech-bubble" id="foo">click to copy text</p>
    <!--p class="cop" id="p">text copied to clipoard</p-->
    <!--p id="copied" class="copied"></p-->
    </form>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i asked this question before, but it was closed ad i was directed to a post that did not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding your issue correctly then what is happening is, you are  setting a transition on opacity on `.speech-bubble` ( `transition: opacity 200ms` ) which without your second transition is fading the opacity in and out on hover. Now when you add your second transition to `.button:hover + .speech-bubble` ( `transition: width 100ms;` ) this is basically saying ignore any other transition property and only transition on width. So this subsequently ignores your first transition when you initially hover over the copy button.

Now to fix this issue you can chain transition types. Basically instead of using `transition: width 100ms;` you can use `transition: opacity 200ms, width 100ms;` This then retains your transition on opacity as well as adding one for your width.

Hope that helps.